# Mask for clearing m bits after n LSBits

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit

I was asked this question in an interview to clear m bits after n bits of a 16 bit integer.

Lets say the number is 10010010010100101. Clear three bits after 5 bits from the LSBit.

Before:    10011001**110**11001
After :    10011001**000**11001

My solution for the mask was `(~0 << (m+n))+((1<<n)-1)`

Is there any solution better than this?

Comment: One of my suggestions would be to not limit yourself to doing it all by bit operations. A solution that would be easy to see its correctness is to have a lookup table for bits strings of [0'b1, 0'b11, 0'b111, ...] and then use this table to get masks of m that can be shifted by n.

Comment: Your example shows clearing after 5 bits from the right

Comment: FWIW, [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) might be a "better" solution

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure about "better", but I always seem to build masks the same way.

```
((1u<<m)-1)<<n
```

For m=3 n=5 this gives

```
000011100000
```

Then using this mask to clear those bits from another value,

```
x & ~(((1u<<m)-1)<<n)
```

Comment: If he's actually looking to do this from the left, it would have to be 16 - n I guess

Comment: Yes. I suppose so. Then it's the same number of ops. If it's really from the right, then I count 5 in mine, 6 in OP.

Comment: Suggest using unsigned integers: `(1u<<m)-1 << n`