# Bit operation Left Shift Python on big integers

Tags: python, integer, bit, shift

I am trying to implement a left bit shift on python with big integers. Because of their size, I want to stock their bit value on a file and work on the file after, as far as the bit string it too big for my RAM.
However, I am facing problem deleting the N first bits of the int without using its binary representation, as far as I can't.
Here is what I did so far:

```
def __lshift(self, n, d):
    N = n.bit_length()
    if N > 2**20: # n is big and we have to use files
        temp = open('bin.tmp','w')
        while N > 2**20:
            n_ = n >> 20 # Take the 20 first bits of n
            temp.write(bin(n)[2:])
            # Here I would like to delete 20 first bits of n
    else:
        bin_ = bin(n)[2:]
        bin_ = bin_[:N-d] + bin_[d:]
        return int(bin_,2)
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: How are you representing the numbers if they're too big for RAM? Are you using some kind of compression?

Comment: No, the binary string is too big, but not the int itself :)

Comment: What is `[2:]` after you call `bin(n)`?

Comment: Python has built-in big integers, why are you implementing this yourself? Is this just an academic exercise?

Comment: You don't need to convert it to a binary string. Just use masking and shifting to get each block of bits.

Comment: i use shifting to get the first bits ``n_ = n >> 20`` but after this i dont know how to delete those bits @Barmar
thank you for your answers !

Comment: Use masking: `n_ = n_ & ~(1 << N)`

Comment: Oh I did not know that ! Do you have some docs that I can read, or maybe is it easy to find #RTFM xD ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28061377/mask-for-clearing-m-bits-after-n-lsbits

Comment: Thank you ! it is ``n_ = n_ & ~(1 << N-1)`` right ? As far as ``n_ = n_ & ~(1 << N)`` does not seem to change anything because it is too big

Comment: That doesn't look like a "left shift". For example, `print(bin(__lshift(None, 0b10101, 4)))` prints `0b11`. How does that make sense?

Comment: Also, you say "deleting the N first bits" and your N is `n.bit_length()`, so you want to delete **all** bits? How does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution I finally found :

```
def lshift(n,d):
def one_turn(n):
    N = n.bit_length()
    end = n >> N-1
    begin = (n & ((1 + (1 << N-1) - 1) ^ ((1 << N) - 1))) << 1
    return begin + end

for i in range(d):
    n = one_turn(n)
return n
```

Finally easier than what I was trying to do :)